# Heroku Python: What is the proper way to set and get cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, heroku, localhost

I've seen many ways to set like:

```
# store in a cookie
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
cookie['lat'] = lat
cookie['lon'] = lon
# expires in one hour
cookie['lat']['expires'] = time.time() + 1 * 24 * 3600 
cookie['lon']['expires'] = time.time() + 1 * 24 * 3600 
print cookie
```

and to check like:

```
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE'))
lat = float(cookie['lat'].value)
lon = float(cookie['lon'].value)
```

but none of them seem to work on my localhost.  Is that a function of my code or it being on localhost.  I haven't done much dev w/cookies before and don't really know the proper way to store things like user login data and data for my app.

Comment: Storing a users geo position to a cookie is a serious privacy concern! You do realize their lat/long will be sent back and forth with every page request from your web server over a public network? It may be better to encrypt the data or store it on the server with a key.

Comment: yes i know, but storing it in a cookie for testing is much easier and simpler for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a url redirect:

```
from flask import make_response, redirect, url_for

response = make_response(redirect('/'))

lat = request.form['lat']
lon = request.form['lon']
response.set_cookie('lat', lat)
response.set_cookie('lon', lon)

return response
```

This is how to get the cookie:

```
lat = float(request.cookies['lat'])
lon = float(request.cookies['lon'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the os.environ with the current request's environ. They are completely different things. The os environ is local to your machine it has nothing to do with the webserver.

For the environ that you're looking for, you need to be inside a web-server when it processes a request.

Maybe this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_request#Technical_overview

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused about how they worked.  I think I answered my own question in my answer.  Thanks for the article!